# Encrypting with a substitution cipher

Tags: cipher

I think I went a little overboard, but I made this substitution cipher:

> MLp;LoyzLpjLhnodLpjLMLjdd;WpfqyoRL;dLhyfL"d!!nolLpoqLzd!!nolL"yvLlfddoLlpfqdojOfdLoyzL4cpzDjLlfy4nolLnoL;"Lej"rcdRLnzDjLpLqnhhdfdozL;dOLqnhhnrv!zLudpjzRLhdpjznolL!v;udfdqLuvfozLqy4oLzfddjJfdd.dLhfp;dRLe!dpjdL!dzL;dLepnozLpL;dozp!LenrzvfdLeyfzfpnzKy;dzcnolL"yvL4yoDzLhyfldzRLnzDjLp!!LpuyvzL;"LhyfdcdpqOoqLcy4LnzLnjLpLqyyfLzcpzLcy!qjLupr'LryozdozjXcpzL;p'djLWpoqyfpDjLuy@LryozdozjL!yy'Loyo1ny!dozYdcnoqL;"Ld"d!nqjLpfdLnj!poqjLyhL1ny!dord:"L;noqLjcne4fdr'dqLzcnjLnjLzcdLyo!"L!poqL;"L;noqLryv!qLhnoqMLqnqLoyzL'oy4LnzL4pjLjvrcLpL1ny!dozLnj!poqJv!!LyhLznqp!L4p1djRLjvnrnqp!Lrfp.dqL!nyojXcd"DfdLzf"nolLzyLdpzL;dRLu!yyqLfvoonolLqy4oLzcdnfLrcnoOoqLML'oy4LzcpzLMLrpoLhnlczRLyfLMLrpoL!dzLzcdL!nyoL4noMLudlnoLzyLpjjd;u!dL4cpzL4dpeyojLMLrpoLhnoqEpvjdLjy;dzn;djLzyLjzp"Lp!n1dL"yvLlyzzpL'n!!L"yvfL;noq

Hint #1:

> If u = b, U may **NOT** = B

Hint #2:

> The (space ) character is L.

Hint #3:

> Some letters may be substitutions for symbols, e.g. @ may equal M, the same goes for numbers.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 9):

After a lot of substitution I get (after adding new lines):

> I am not as fine as I seem
> Pardon, me for yelling and telling you green gardens
> Are not what's growing in my psyche, it's a different me
> A difficult beast, feasting lumbered burnt down trees
> Freeze frame, please let me paint a mental picture portrait
> Something you won't forget, it's all about my forehead
> And how it is a door that holds back contents
> That makes Pandora's box contents look nonviolent
> Behind my eyelids are islands of violence
> My mind shipwrecked this is the only land my mind could find
> I did not know it was such a violent island
> Full of tidal waves, suicidal crazed lions
> They're trying to eat me, blood running down their chin
> And I know that I can fight, or I can let the lion win
> I begin to assemble what weapons I can find
> Cause sometimes to stay alive you gotta kill your mind

.

> Looks like the lyrics to Migraine by Twenty One Pilots.

Substitution table:

> ```
>  !| l
>  "| y
>  '| k
>  .| z
>  1| v
>  4| w
>  :| M
>  ;| m
>  @| x
>  D| '
>  E| C
>  J| F
>  K| S
>  L| space
>  M| I
>  O| A
>  R| ,
>  W| P
>  X| T
>  Y| B
>  c| h
>  d| e
>  e| p
>  f| r
>  h| f
>  j| s
>  l| g
>  n| i
>  o| n
>  p| a
>  q| d
>  r| c
>  u| b
>  v| u
>  y| o
>  z| t
> ```